# How can I remove a stylesheet when I only know part of the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to remove a css stylesheet using JS/jquery.

I know it will be in the 'head' element and contain the text: civicrm.css but I don't know the rest of the url.

Is it something like?:

```
if $("head:contains('civicrm.css')") {

remove the entire link it is part of.

}
```

At the moment I'm just doing this:

`('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="/thelinkaddress/civicrm.css?r=vrigl"]').remove()`

But the last few letters change often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = 'civicrm.css';
$("link[href*='"+ str +"']").remove();

// another way

$('link').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf(str) > -1) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/japbjrzc/3/**

Answer (score 3):

```js
// grab all <link />
var stylesheets = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
for (var s = 0; s < stylesheets.length; s++){
  var stylesheet = stylesheets[s];
  // determine if it contains /bootstrap.min.css.css
  if (stylesheet.href.indexOf('/bootstrap.min.css') > -1){
    // remove element
    stylesheet.parentNode.removeChild(stylesheet);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css?cacheBuster=123456" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="well">
  <p>I'm in a well.</p>
</div>
```

jQuery version:

```js
$('link[href*="/bootstrap.min.css"]').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css?cacheBuster=abc123" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="well">
  <p>I'm in a well.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

w3schools says to the ~= css attribute selector:

> The [attribute~=value] selector is used to select elements with an attribute value containing a specified word.

So you only have to remove the versioning string

```
('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="/thelinkaddress/civicrm.css"]').remove()
```

Try it =)

Comment: [`~=`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/) is for locating attributes containing a word, where as [`*=`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) is for locating attributes containing a value (note the context of "word")

Comment: yes your right =), thanks for the clean seperation of these two attributes :)

Comment: off topic, but It's best to reference MDN instead of W3Schools http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[Attribute Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)**.

```js
$( '[rel="stylesheet"][href*="civicrm.css"]' ).remove( );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"> test.css </div>
<div rel="stylesheet" href="civicrm.css"> civicrm.css </div>
<div rel="stylesheet" href="/thelinkaddress/civicrm.css?r=vrigl"> /thelinkaddress/civicrm.css?r=vrigl </div>
```

For the sake of demo, I used `div` instead of `link`.